# get the text of div not span

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this demo and try to get the text of div.

```
<script>
var string = "<span>this is span</span>new line";
var anchors = $('<div/>').append(string).find('span').text();
console.log(anchors);
</script>
```

**div look like**

```
<div>
   <span>this is span</span>
   new line
</div>
```

**output:-**

```
this is span
```

and want to `new line`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try like this

if div had an id foo  or class foo

```
$("#foo") //can not use div as will target all the divs
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Alternatively

```
$("#foo").contents()
.filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text()
```

## [DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmmy2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just implement like this:

```
var anchors = $('<div/>').append(string).text();//find() is removed as it will find the text not html span.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Could use regex](http://jsbin.com/fafoyoke/1/edit)

JS:

```
var string = "<span>this is span</span>new line<a>I don't want this</a>";

// finds "<word>text</word>" and replaces with ""
string = string.replace(/<[a-zA-Z]+>[^(<\/)]*<\/[a-zA-Z]+>/g, function(){
  return "";
});

alert(string); // "new line"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should find all the text nodes in a div (with the right selector)

```
console.log($('div').contents()
.filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text())
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var string = "<span>this is span</span>new line";
var jdiv = $('<div/>');
var jspan = jdiv.append(string).find('span');
//get whatever you want
jspan.text();//
jdiv.text();//
```